# Fancybox image size in modal

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, fancybox-2

I need to know fancybox 2 image size in div fancybox-image

I want to add div under fancybox that is 100% of the image. Problem is that I cannot have 100% width div, I tried adding box-sizing property...etc the only way div can have the good size is to add jquery div size class:

```
$(".divtitle").css("width", ""+imgsize +"px");
```

Problem is that I need to know the current image size in lightbox, to add class to div.
I tried:

```
var imgsize = $(".fancybox-image").width();
```

It works if only 1 image in fancybox, but when using gallery, it returns the size of the next image in gallery

I think I should use something like:

var imgsize = $this.find(".fancybox-image").width(); but not working...

[image]

Comment: Blue (caption) div is in question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to append a `DIV` to place the `title`, then I would rather manipulate the fancybox `title` selector to get the same effect so :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    padding: 0,
    helpers: {
        title: {
            type: "inside"
        }
    }
});
```

This will generate the selector `.fancybox-title-inside-wrap` that you can manipulate through css like :

```
.fancybox-title-inside-wrap {
    background-color: #33CCFF;
    padding: 5px 10px
}
```

That way you don't have to calculate any size since the `title` will fill the 100% width of the image.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6x67a/)**